# How to extract various parts of a string into separate strings

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I am trying to make a function to help me debug. When I do the following:

```
s = traceback.format_stack()[-2]
print(s)
```

I get a console output something like:

```
File "/home/path/to/dir/filename.py", line 888, in function_name
```

How can I extract `filename.py`, `888` and `function_name` into separate strings? Using a regex?

Comment: Instead of extracting the traceback parameters from the string, get them directly with the help of `traceback` or `inspect` modules, e.g. [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1650970/771848) or [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961750/locating-the-line-number-where-an-exception-occurs-in-python-code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = 'File "/home/path/to/dir/filename.py", line 888, in function_name'

search = re.search('File (.*), line (.*), in (.*)', string, re.IGNORECASE)
print search.group(1)
print search.group(2)
print search.group(3)
```

Comment: this is my favourite solution because its so human-readable. hadn't heard of `re.search()` before. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use str.split():

```
>>> s = 'File "/home/path/to/dir/filename.py", line 888, in function_name'
>>> lst = s.split(',')
>>> lst
['File "/home/path/to/dir/filename.py"', ' line 888', ' in function_name']
```

so for the 888 and function_name, you can access them like this

```
>>> lst[1].split()[1]
>>> '888'
```

and for the filename.py, you can split it by '"'

```
>>> fst = lst[0].split('"')[1]
>>> fst
'/home/path/to/dir/filename.py'
```

then you can use os.path.basename:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.basename(fst)
'filename.py'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this regular expression:

```
File \"[a-zA-Z\/_]*\/([a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]+)", line ([0-9]+), in (.*)
```

you can try using this site: https://regex101.com/