# Get last function's arguments from traceback?

Tags: python, exception, stack-trace

I read [Get last function's call arguments from traceback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650713/get-last-functions-call-arguments-from-traceback) but it is not specific enough to answer my problem.

This is really bothering me since not having the call arguments is slowing me down and I am pretty sure that it is possible to get this kind of info from Python.

Here is an example to illustrate the problem:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import traceback
import inspect
import logging as log

def fl(x):
    # exception is happening here
    y = 5/x
    return y


def fm(x):
    return fl(x-3)


def fn(a, b, c=None):
    return fm(c)


def main():

    try:
        print fn(1, 2, c=3)
    except Exception as e:
        log.error('Unexpected problem.')
        log.error(e)
        traceback.print_exc()
        ### what I need to see is are the call arguments of the last / deepest call: ###
        ### def fl(x) was called with arguments: [(x, 3)]                            ###
        # this does not cut it:
        tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
        traceback.print_tb(tb)
        # this is broken:
        #frames = inspect.getinnerframes(tb)
        #log.error('Argvalues: %s', inspect.getargvalues(frames))
        # not sure:
        frames = inspect.trace()
        argvalues = inspect.getargvalues(frames[0][0])
        log.error('Argvalues: %s', inspect.formatargvalues(*argvalues))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

so I get details, but the call arguments are not contained:

```
ERROR:root:Unexpected problem.
ERROR:root:integer division or modulo by zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 24, in main
    print fn(1, 2, c=3)
  File "sample.py", line 18, in fn
    return fm(c)
  File "sample.py", line 14, in fm
    return fl(x-3)
  File "sample.py", line 9, in fl
    y = 5/x
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
  File "sample.py", line 24, in main
    print fn(1, 2, c=3)
  File "sample.py", line 18, in fn
    return fm(c)
  File "sample.py", line 14, in fm
    return fl(x-3)
  File "sample.py", line 9, in fl
    y = 5/x
ERROR:root:Argvalues: ()
```

Comment: What does *"not cut it"* mean, in this context? What does *"broken"* mean? Why are you *"not sure"*?

Comment: not sure how to say this so it is easy to understand... I need this info "def fl(x) was called with arguments: [(x, 3)]" to be contained in the log. I call this last function arguments...

Comment: I'm simply asking you to explain your own comments; presumably you've run that code, and could expand on the three comments identified. I find *"not sure"* particularly baffling.

Comment: I see, I ran the code and the log output is contained in the bottom part of my question as you can see. all three attempts in the sample are answers of the cited question and do not provide the info.

Comment: So *what are you unsure about?* As a side note, have you considered where e.g. `main` would fit into this?

Comment: @mark, `frames[0]` is `main`, `frames[-1]` is `fl`

Comment: @DJV:  so "argvalues = inspect.getargvalues(frames[-1][0])" gets me what I need. very helpful - thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`frames[0][0]` represents `main` function. `main` is called without arguments, thats why you get empty tuple. Change it to `frames[-1][0]` to get last frame.

Comment: I just added this to my code and it works like a charm. Having the last call arguments in the log is so helpful. I wounder why it is not better advertised / more obvious. Anyway, thank you again.